# Using a Resource File on buttons OnClientClick

Tags: c#, asp.net

I would like to use a resource file to display the dialog box which is displayed on client click, i have tried the below however I am getting the result in the screen shot:

```
               <asp:Button ID="editview" runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:btnEditViewText%>"  CssClass="buttonlink"                         
               OnClientClick="return confirm('<%$ Resources:btnEditViewText%>');"
               CommandName="editview" 
               CommandArgument='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Id")%>'/>
```

[image]

I have seen a few people suggest setting this in the code behind however this control is wrapped in a repeater and I can only get a handle on it once the `ItemCommand` event is triggered which requires the confirmation dialogue to have been confirmed.

This feels like a bit of a catch 22 and im out of ideas, any suggestions guys?

Comment: You can set it in the code behind within the repeater's ItemDataBound event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Ben, this worked

```
    protected void rptVessels_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        Button button = (Button)e.Item.FindControl("editview");
        button.OnClientClick = String.Format("return confirm('{0}')", GetLocalResourceObject("alertEditVesselText").ToString());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my code and it works! But I also prefer code behind solution especially for single controls.

In my project, i use this in nested repeaters so I do not need to use OnItemDataBound method. Its so easy...

```
OnClientClick='<%#String.Concat("if ( !confirm(\u0027", Resources.Resource.AreYouSureToDelete, "\u0027)) return false;") %>'
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me. It uses the correct resource and shows the correct message, but whatever I click - confirm, cancel or even if I just close the alert box - the result is always the same and the record is deleted.

Answer (score -1):

I found the best solution

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function DeleteItem() {
        if (confirm(document.getElementById('<%=hdelete.ClientID%>').value)) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
 </script>

 <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hdelete" Value="<%$Resources:Resources, Confiemdelete %>" />
 <asp:Button ID="btnmergewithname" runat="server"  Text="<%$Resources:Resources, Delete %>" OnClientClick="return DeleteItem()"/>
```

Comment: <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hdelete" Value="<%$Resources:Resources, Confiemdelete %>"/>

<asp:Button ID="btndelete" runat="server"  Text="<%$Resources:Resources, delete %>" OnClientClick="return DeleteItem()"/>